# Protractor debugging doesnt start, Debugger listening on port 5858

Tags: angularjs, selenium, webdriver, protractor

I am trying to debug my protractor tests but for the starting point I am just trying to explore elementExplorer.
When I type in `protractor --elementExplorer` I get the following output and chrome opens up with `data:,`.
This is what I see on console:

`Starting selenium standalone server...`

`Selenium standalone server started at http://MYIPADDRESS:59672/wd/hub`

`Starting debugger agent.`

`Debugger listening on port 5858`

Nothing happens after this for many minutes and I cannot even type into the Node.js cmd prompt as it just hangs there. Can get out of that with Ctrl C.

FYI my protractor tests run fine but only debug doesnt work.

Comment: I got a problem telling me that port 5858 is already in use while debugging my script !

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue, the work around I use is to run "protractor debug" and add a `browser.pause();` in my code.

If you do this you should see `debug>` prompt when it hits the `browser.pause();`, enter "c" to let it proceed until it hits the `browser.pause();` and then enter `repl`

```
connecting to port 5858... ok                                                       
debug> c                                                                            
debug> Selenium standalone server started at http://10.3.3.227:60726/wd/hub
break in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:70                                                                  
debug> repl                                                                         
Press Ctrl + C to leave debug repl                                                  
>
```